# Thermodynamic compression of gas under a massive load

Tags: thermodynamics

The given problem is from 200 puzzling physics.
It states
A horizontal frictionless piston, of negligible mass and heat capacity, divides a vertical insulated cylinder into two halves. Each half of the cylinder contains 1 mole of air at standard temperature and pressure P.A load W is now suspended from the piston, as shown in the figure. It pulls the piston and comes to rest after a few oscillilations. How large a volume does the compressed part in the lower cylinder ultimately occupy?

Now even I had solved the problem upto a point given in the solution but I had a few extra variables,
The solution states that in the final state the final temperature of both the parts must be equal.
It provides no further proof, Now I have no idea why it must be so, the piston is not conducting?Then why is this a condition for the final state.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the piston has both negligible mass and heat capacity means it is to be considered infinitely thin; heat is then conveyed instantaneously through it. It is in a sense a trick question; to be fair and explicit it should also specify that the piston is a perfect conductor of heat.

Comment: Oh I see, I never get what is the point of writing such statements, they should clearly state the conditions